# Can you create a table output from the 'feature statistics' tool in Orange?

Tags: statistics, orange

I really like the feature statistics tool in Orange, but am unclear on how to go from a graphical output to a data table that would include min/max, standard deviation etc. for a given target class.

Is there another way to generate these kinds of basic statistics for numerical data in Orange? And to group the data by other class variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Connect "Feature Statistics" to "Data Table". Double click the connection. In the dialog that opens, click the line between "Reduced Data" and "Data", so that it will disappear, and connect "Statistics" to "Data".

Now you can choose some (or all) variables in "Feature Statistics" and you will see their statistics in the "Data Table".

I hope this answers the question -- I am not sure about what you meant by "grouping by other class variables".

You may want to check Pivot Table, too.